# Возникает проблема IndentationError: unexpected indent python

Tags: python

Возникает проблема в коде. При попытке убрать табы или их добавить проблема не меняется.

```
print (jesterlogo)
print (jesterlogd)
choice = raw_input()
cls()
    if choice == "1":
        informationjester()
        elif choice == "2":
            itispranksbro()
            self.__init__()`
```

Сама ошибка:

```
if choice == "1":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: А зачем вам отступ перед if ?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо вашего

```
print (jesterlogo)
print (jesterlogd)
choice = raw_input()
cls()
    if choice == "1":
        informationjester()
        elif choice == "2":
            itispranksbro()
            self.__init__()`
```

используйте

```
print (jesterlogo)
print (jesterlogd)
choice = raw_input()
cls()
if choice == "1":
    informationjester()
elif choice == "2":
    itispranksbro()
    self.__init__()
```

Comment: `elif`, вероятно, также следует сместить влево.

Comment: @Something, спасибо, исправил.